# converting hex to base64 - what really happens in this process?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, base64, hex

in attempt to make simple code to convert a hex string to base64:

my thought was: hex -> integer -> binary -> base64

so i wrote this little code:

```
import string


def bit(integer):
    # To binary
    return int(bin(integer))[2:]


#Hex multiply by 16 depending on position: 0xAB = A*(16**2) + B(16**1) = #10*16**2 + 11*16**1
    #0x3a2f
    #3*(16**2) + 7*(16**1) + 5


def removeletter(list):
    #"abcdef" = "10 11 12 13 14 15"

    for i, letter in enumerate(list):
        if letter in hextable.keys():
            list[i] = hextable[letter]
        
    return list



def todecimal(h):   
    power = 0
    l = [num for num in str(h)] #['3', 'a', '2', 'f']
    l = removeletter(l)
    l.reverse()                       #['f', '2', 'a', '3'] 

    for i, n in enumerate(l):
        
        number = int(n)
        l[i] = number*(16**power)
        power += 1

    l.reverse()
    return sum(l)


lowers = string.ascii_lowercase



hextable = {}
for number, letter in enumerate(lowers[:6]):
    hextable[letter] = number + 10
```

in this little challenge i am doing, it says:

```
 The string:

49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d

Should produce:

SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t
```

ok,
`print(bit(todecimal('49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d')))`

this should get the binary of the hex string, which if I put through a binary to base64 converter, should return `SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t`. or so i thought.

```
└─$ python3 hextobase64.py
10010010010011101101101001000000110101101101001011011000110110001101001011011100110011100100000011110010110111101110101011100100010000001100010011100100110000101101001011011100010000001101100011010010110101101100101001000000110000100100000011100000110111101101001011100110110111101101110011011110111010101110011001000000110110101110101011100110110100001110010011011110110111101101101
```

after checking using a hex to binary converter, i can see that the binary is correct.
now, if if i put this through a binary to base64 converter, it should return  `SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t`, right?

the thing is, [this binary to base64 converter](https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-to-base64) gave me `kk7aQNbS2NjS3M5A8t7q5EDE5MLS3EDY0tbKQMJA4N7S5t7c3urmQNrq5tDk3t7a` which is odd to me. so I must be doing something wrong. from my understanding, hexadecimal can be represented in binary, and so can base64. base64 takes the binary and groups the binary by 6 digits to produce its own representation. so obviously if I have the binary, it should be interchangeable, but something is wrong.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: since you know the answer, you can decode the expected base64 result to binary and compare it with your binary value. This will give you a hint what's going on.

Comment: @janwilamowski putting the answer through base64 -> binary, [i can see here](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-binary) that the bits are sequenced in 8, which, from my understanding, should be sequenced in 6 bits. then each group of bits can be represented using a base64 table. i don't quite understand.

Comment: you probably only selected grouping by bytes instead of 6 bits. That shouldn't make a difference. Ignore the grouping and directly compare the binary strings.

Comment: @janwilamowski the binary strings are different, why is that?

Comment: you're missing a leading zero